# Flask deployment server redirects add server name to address

Tags: python, redirect, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I configured Nginx as a reverse proxy to a Gunicorn server running on 127.0.0.1:8000.

Nginx configuration is like this:

```
server {
        server_name www.programlama.tk;
        rewrite ^ http://programlama.tk/ permanent;
}

server {
listen 80;  # listen onport 80
server_name programlama.tk localhost; #requests to this domain or ip

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   }
}
```

So far so good. In my flask application when the user authenticates there is a simple method that redirects to the user's home page which is 'ev'. 'Ev' means home.

```
@app.route('/ev')
def ev():
    return render_template('ev.html')
```

But instead of *http://programlama.tk/ev* this, it redirects to

> http://programlama.tk%2Cprogramlama.tk/ev

this address, which doesn't exist. Also, it adds the server name to the redirect address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the nginx configuration a bit [as described in the documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#proxy-setups).

Now it works as expected.

```
location / {
    proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
    proxy_redirect     off;

    proxy_set_header   Host                 $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto    $scheme;
}
```